# Which graph algorithms are available in Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I know that there are like 100s of graph algorithms out there. Which one are available in Memgraph? Is there some command like `help list algorithms` that would tell me what can I use?

Comment: https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/available-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no Cypher command that would list all of the available/implemented graph algorithms.

If you have "pure" Memgraph then you have:

- Depth-first search (DFS)
- Breadth-first search (BFS)
- Weighted shortest path (WSP)
- All shortest paths (ASP)

This are [built in graph algorithms](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms).

As Iłya Bursov has written in his comment there is also MAGE. It is an open-source repository that contains graph algorithms and modules written by the team behind Memgraph and its users in the form of query modules.

At the moment MAGE includes the following algorithms:

- Betweenness Centrality
- Biconnected Components
- Bipartite Matching
- Bridge Detection
- Community Detection
- Cycle Detection
- Graph Coloring
- Katz Centrality
- Maximum Flow
- Node Similarity
- PageRank
- Union Find
- Dynamic Betweenness Centrality
- Dynamic Community Detection
- Dynamic node2vec
- Dynamic Katz Centrality
- Dynamic PageRank

A complete list of algorithms and implementation details within MAGE can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms.